# Backtrader fail to show plot graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, backtrader

I am new to coding, trying to use backtrader to do a simple backtesting process. I was able to execute the buy and sell, but when i am trying to plot the graph it shows:
**AttributeError: type object 'Gcf' has no attribute '_set_new_active_manager'**

My code is as below:

```py
print('Starting Portfolio Value: %.2f' % cerebro.broker.getvalue())

cerebro.run()

print('Final Portfolio Value: %.2f' % cerebro.broker.getvalue())

cerebro.plot()
```

See if any one can offer some help, many thanks.

Comment: I'v run into a similar problem with `AttributeError: 'OptReturn' object has no attribute 'datas'`

Answer (score 1):

The problem doesn't seem to be printing the data. You are making an error initializing an object. You need to share the other part of the code.

I wanted to help you by developing a test application. The test application was based on the [Plotting](https://www.backtrader.com/docu/plotting/plotting/) application. I used [this link](https://github.com/mementum/backtrader/pull/418) to fix the *"Fix ImportError from matplotlib.dates"* error. I used [this link](https://github.com/mementum/backtrader/tree/master/datas) to use the test data (`2005-2006-day-001.txt`) in the application. Below is a demo sample:

```py
from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals)

import backtrader as bt

class St(bt.Strategy):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sma = bt.indicators.SimpleMovingAverage(self.data)


data = bt.feeds.BacktraderCSVData(dataname='dataset.txt')

cerebro = bt.Cerebro()
cerebro.adddata(data)
cerebro.addstrategy(St)
cerebro.run()
cerebro.plot()
```

Current `matplot` version causes *"Fix ImportError from matplotlib.dates"*. The way to avoid this error is to use older `matplot` version by running the following codes:

```sh
pip uninstall matplotlib
pip install matplotlib==3.1.1
```

Below is the application test image:

[image]